# because I can not get the ajax data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax request that will pass some data to an action of a controller of cakephp 3, but the controller does not receive the data, $ _POST equal to empty.

```
var url = "http://localhost/update/"+ id;

var telefone = 9999999;
var cpf = 999999999;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: {cpf: cpf, celular: telefone}
}).done(function( response ) {  

}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {

});
```

method receive data:

```
public function update($id = null) {
    var_dump($_POST);die();
}
```

my var_dump show empty, but i send data in Ajax.
allow access in method! someone have this problem?

Comment: Well, you aren't doing anything with the response. How can you tell the `$_POST` is empty?

Comment: @Don'tPanic this might actually be *quite* bad if that is it. Completely missed that...

Comment: var_dump shows me what's inside the $ _POST and the result is "array (size = 0) empty"

Comment: Shot in the dark: There's a redirect happening. Side note: Never access superglobals directly in CakePHP, use the proper wrappers, in this case `Request::data()` (**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data**).

Comment: $this->request->data is empty too

Comment: That's to be expected if `$_POST` is, it was just a "side note". You'll run into problems especially in the test environment when using superglobals. As for you problem, do some browser console debugging and update your question with details of what's happening, don't let people guess all day.

Comment: but it was to receive the value of $ POST the same way, I am passing the data "POST"

Answer (score 0):

don't you need to specify the port in the url? for example `http://localhost:8080/update/`

Comment: is not it, url is example, i have other url and url not is problem ;/

Answer (score 0):

type should be POST like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    // blah blah
```

Comment: Are you expecting id value or cpf and celular values at serverside (in $_POST) ?

Comment: id I receive, but i need celular and cpf too!

Answer (score 0):

Use fireBug to see if the request is sending anything.With this tool you can track your request. The most likely you're not sending the data correctly.

Comment: the problem is that it sends the request. POSTMAN I used to simulate a POST and see if the url is receiving, the simulation gave OK and received data. Now when I try to send by ajax, it makes the request but does not receive the data being sent by post

Comment: have you tryied checking your data like this:

    $this->request->data('cpf');
?
@FelipeXavier